# String Cannot Be Converted To Int

Tags: java, string, for-loop, int

This is just a little bit of my code, but I am trying to loop through two strings, get the value of the first number in one string, and then use that number as the position to find in the other string, then add that word into a new string. But it comes up with the error "String cannot be converted to int" can anyone help?

```
        String result = "";   

        for (int i = 0; i < wordPositions.length; i++){
           result += singleWords[wordPositions[i]];
        }
```

Comment: Is `wordPositions` an int array?

Comment: What are the types of `wordPositions` and `singleWords`?

Comment: `result += "" + singleWords[wordPositions[i]];`

Comment: Neither wordPositions or singleWords are int arrays, they are "String[] wordPositions" and "String[] singleWords"

Comment: So what do you expect to get with `singleWords[someString]`? Array indexes are ints. Make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need further help

Comment: I need wordPositions to be an int so that in singleWords[wordPositions[i]], wordPositions[i], will find that position in singleWords

Answer (score 0):

Use this to convert String into int

```
Integer.parseInt(integerString);
```

The completed line of code:

```
result += singleWords[Integer.parseInt(wordPositions[i])];
```

Comment: Please include more context/explanation for the code to make the answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

if your wordPositions is a String array when you do this:

```
  result += singleWords[wordPositions[i]];
```

it like if you does this

```
result += singleWords["value of the wordPositions array at index i"];
```

but is need to be an int in [] not a string that why you have the exception String can not be cast to Int

Answer (score 0):

If wordPositions is an array of numbers inside a string for example

```
String[] wordPositions = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
```

Then you nees to use

```
Integer.parseInt(NUMBER_IN_STRING);
```

To change the string value to an int value.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because wordPositions[i] returns a string and you need to convert it to int before trying to acess singlewords[].

```
result += singleWords[Integer.parseInt(wordPositions[i])];
```

Comment: After I do this, it gets rid of the error message, but it still does not work when I try to print out the string result.

Comment: @MichaelCollins what error do you get when you try to print result?